# How to concatenate two strings in a <img> src tag?

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I want to concatenate two strings inside a `<img>` tag. How to do this??

```
<img src=" "/partners" + @item.AdPath" alt="" id="adimg" title="@item.AdName"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I see many strings inside your `<img>` tag. Which ones do you need to concatenate? Or in other words: What output do you expect?

Comment: i want to concatenate /partners with @item.AdPath

Comment: output should be like /partners+adpathvalues

Comment: Have you tried by using Server Tags `<%= item.AdPath  %>`

Comment: @RJK: He's using razor, not asp, so the `@` is the tag indicating server-side logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should simply be able to do this:

```
<img src="/partners+@(item.AdPath)" alt="" id="adimg"
    title="@item.AdName"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```

The Razor engine will replace `@item.AdPath` with the actual value, giving you `src="/partners+[value]"`.

Since the Razor expression is the only thing that's parsed, you don't have to try and work string concatenation logic into the tag - simply drop in the Razor expression where you want the value to appear.

Edit: Or, if you don't want the plus sign (not clear from your comments):

```
<img src="/partners@(item.AdPath)" alt="" id="adimg"
    title="@item.AdName"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```

Alternatively, you could try with `String.Format`:

```
<img src="@String.Format("/partners{0}", item.AdPath)" alt="" id="adimg"
    title="@item.AdName"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```

Comment: If i give it like this /partners@item.AdPath.......am getting like this /partners@item.AdPath...and not the @item.AdPath value

Comment: i need  /partners string with @item.AdPath value

Comment: Odd, that should work. Are your other Razor expressions parsed? Try my last update using `String.Format` or wrapping the Razor expressions in brackets.

Comment: The reason `/partners@item.AdPath` doens't work is that razor uses intelligent recognintion for email adresses. It has evaluated that this is an email address and should not be interpreted as a razor expression, which is why that one comes out wrong. So int hat case the `@(abc.xyz)`syntax can be used, making razor understand it's not an email address.

Comment: @RenéWolferink Interesting! Did not know that. I suppose it's sensible to disambiguate with parentheses in these scenarios, regardless.

Comment: Hi if i want to concatenate item.AdPath + item.Status means what should i do??

Comment: If you're using `String.Format` - `src="@String.Format("/partners{0}{1}", item.AdPath, item.Status)"`

Answer (score 2):

It could be done like this:

First:

```
<img src="@("/partners" + item.AdPath)" alt="" id="adimg" title="@item.AdName"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```

Second:

```
<img src="/partners@(item.AdPath)" alt="" id="adimg" title="@item.AdName"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 I did:

```
 <img src="{{basePath  + Data.id +'/' + Data.id + '_0.jpg'}}">
```

`basePath` and `Data.id` are variables and whatever is in between `''` like `'/'` and `'_0.jpg'` is just what I want to concatenate to those variables.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar subfolder image files accessing issue but below code format worked for my application .

```
<img src='<%#: String.Format("~/partners/{0}", item.AdPath) %>'
 alt="" id="adimg" title="<%#:item.AdName%>"  width:"50px" height="50px"/>
```