# How do I concat inside <img src="" in a cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to do something like this.

```
<img src="~/Images/@item.Id" +".jpg" />
```

but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the full code

```
  foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/Images/@item.Id.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081150/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-a-img-src-tag/16081255  is not answer your question?

Comment: No it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src='~/images/@(item.Id+".jpg")'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
foreach (var item in Model) 
{
        var image_link = "~/Images/" + @item.Id + ".jpg"
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="@image_link" />
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```